# Coding a Button to display a list of items in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, listbox, radio-button

I'm having tremendous trouble in coding a Button that will display items, that I have selected in a program, in a ListBox.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        If rdoNormal.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = 1.05
        ElseIf rdoThicc.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = 1.05
        ElseIf rdoCrusty.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = 1.05
        ElseIf rdoCob.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = 1.05
        End If

        If rdoSausage.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = Val(txtTotal.Text) + 1.8
        ElseIf rdoTurkey.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = Val(txtTotal.Text) + 3.25
        ElseIf rdoCheese.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = Val(txtTotal.Text) + 2.4
        ElseIf rdoPopchick.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = Val(txtTotal.Text) + 0.84
        End If

        If chkMayo.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = Val(txtTotal.Text) + 0.6
        End If

        If chkButter.Checked = True Then
            txtTotal.Text = Val(txtTotal.Text) + 0.6
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        lstReceipt.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReceipt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReceipt.Click
       **(What do I put here?)**
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I guess...

Comment: What I'ld propose is to, well, change everything :) You could have a Receipt class object which is bound to each group of options. When one of the options is modified, the bound class would aumatically recalculate all the values, building a Total and, as a consequence, update the bound ListBox which presents the selected elements. I understand what this implies and you're probably not willing to make this kind of change. You could use some Fields that keep track of the options selected (value and related text) and have the Buttons just sum the values then pass the text + values to the ListBox.

Comment: Are you dealing with more than a single item?  The way you have it setup now is going to be kind of clunky to maintain a running total for multiple items.

Comment: You should set `Option Strict On` right away - it will help you write less kludgy code.  Then learn about the many, more versatile NET alternatives to that legacy `Val` function

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in the list box, you did not state that In your question

Comment: Similar to how someone's order would show up at a place such as Tesco, like in the self service checkout. It shows you what you have scanned and how many times you have scanned certain items. @preciousbetline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came to with some help from an experienced peer (Thank you for attempting to help me):

```
    Private Sub btnReceipt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReceipt.Click
    If rdoNormal.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoNormal.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Normal Bread £1.05")
    End If

    If rdoThick.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoThick.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Thick Bread £1.05")
    End If

    If rdoCrusty.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoCrusty.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Crusty Bread £1.05")
    End If

    If rdoCob.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoCob.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Cob Bread £1.05")
    End If

    If rdoSausage.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoSausage.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Sausage £1.80")
    End If

    If rdoTurkey.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoTurkey.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Turkey £3.25")
    End If

    If rdoCheese.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoCheese.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Cheese £2.40")
    End If

    If rdoPopchick.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoPopchick.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Popcorn Chicken £0.84")
    End If

    If chkMayo.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(chkMayo.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Mayo £0.60")
    End If

    If chkButter.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(chkButter.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Butter £0.60")
    End If

    If rdoKetchup.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoKetchup.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Ketchup £0.00")
    End If

    If rdoBBQ.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoBBQ.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("BBQ £0.00")
    End If

    If rdoBrown.Checked = True Then
        lstReceipt.Text = Val(rdoBrown.Text)
        lstReceipt.Items.Add("Brown £0.00")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably set everything up like this.

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Public ItemList As New List(Of MyItem)

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim NewItem As MyItem = CalculateTotal()
    ItemList.Add(NewItem)

End Sub

Private Function CalculateTotal() As MyItem

    Dim TotalPrice As Decimal = 1.05D
    Dim Description As New StringBuilder

    Select Case True
        Case rdoSausage.Checked
            TotalPrice += 1.8D
            Description.Append("Sausage ")
        Case rdoTurkey.Checked
            TotalPrice += 3.25D
            Description.Append("Turkey ")
        Case rdoCheese.Checked
            TotalPrice += 2.4D
            Description.Append("Cheese ")
        Case rdoPopchick.Checked
            TotalPrice += 0.84D
            Description.Append("Popcorn Chicken ")
    End Select

    If chkMayo.Checked = True Then
        TotalPrice += 0.6D
        Description.Append("Mayo ")
    End If

    If chkButter.Checked = True Then
        TotalPrice += 0.6D
        Description.Append("Butter ")
    End If



    Return New MyItem With {.Description = Description.ToString(), .Price = TotalPrice}
End Function

Private Sub btnReceipt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReceipt.Click
    For Each Item In ItemList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Item.Description & ": " & Item.Price.ToString("C"))
    Next
End Sub
End Class



Public Class MyItem
    Public Property Description() As String
    Public Property Price() As Decimal

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Description & Price.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a ReceiptItem class. This could just as easily been a Structure which would probably be better (lighter value type). Then a List(Of ReceiptItem) stores the objects.

A tiny Fucntion gets the selected radio button. This could be done in a loop which is what the Linq stuff is doing internally.

To make the receipt look better it should really be displayed in a ListView or DataGridView. You can simulate columns in a ListBox with padding and such but you would have to use a monospaced font which is ugly in itself.

```
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim lstItems As New List(Of ReceiptItem)
        Dim SelectedRadioButton1 As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox1)
        lstItems.Add(New ReceiptItem(SelectedRadioButton1.Text, 1.05D))
        Dim SelectedRadioButton2 As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox2)
        lstItems.Add(New ReceiptItem(SelectedRadioButton2.Text, CDec(SelectedRadioButton2.Tag)))
        If chkMayo.Checked = True Then
            lstItems.Add(New ReceiptItem("Mayonaise", 0.6D))
        End If
        If chkButter.Checked = True Then
            lstItems.Add(New ReceiptItem("Butter", 0.6D))
        End If
        FillReceiptListBox(lstItems)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSelectedRadioButton(ctrl As Control) As RadioButton
        Dim rButton As RadioButton = ctrl.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
        Return rButton
    End Function

    Private Sub FillReceiptListBox(lst As List(Of ReceiptItem))
        Dim Total As Decimal
        For Each item In lst
            Total += item.Price
            Dim strPrice As String = item.Price.ToString("N2")
            ListBox1.Items.Add($"{item.Description}  --   {item.Price.ToString("N2")}")
        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Add($"Total    {Total.ToString("C")}")
    End Sub

    Class ReceiptItem
        Public Property Description As String
        Public Property Price As Decimal
        Public Sub New(des As String, p As Decimal)
            Description = des
            Price = p
        End Sub
    End Class
```